# Why did the police officer complain about Ivan not having a passport?

Tags: historical-context, ukrainian-language, maria-matios, sweet-darusya

In *Sweet Darusya*, a police officer brings Ivan to a party Director on a laundry list of complaints, one of which was that he was living in the village without a proper passport. I'm a little confused about that, though. Why was that a problem?

Also, the book doesn't note the Director being overly disturbed by the allegation. Why might that be? Would a local party official be inclined to care about such a violation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [internal passport system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passport_system_in_the_Soviet_Union) was a vital tool for governing the population, because it identified the bearer and allowed him to be regulated.  It was overtly stated that its purpose was

> the removal of persons not engaged in industrial or other socially-useful work from towns and the cleansing of towns from hiding kulaks, criminals and other antisocial elements

Then, in any such practice, much depended on the rigor of the local officials.  Some might severely require it, some might be lax, some might use it as a pretext to play favorites.  A village where everyone knew each other would have little use for its identification value, in particular.